# Laravel route Call to a member function getName() on null

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a very simple trait for the admin site nav that contains array of nav items. I have another method to check the route and set the active class for the item. It is working fine in browsers however in terminal using `artisan` giving me the following error.

### Trait method

```
protected function getActiveClass($routeName)
{
    return (Route::current()->getName() == $routeName) ? 'active' : NULL;
}
```

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to a
>   member function getName() on null

## Trait full code

```
namespace App\Traits;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

trait AdminMenu
{

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function navItems()
    {
        $sideNavItems = [
            [
                'nav'    => 'dashboard',
                'label'  => __('admin.menu.dashboard'),
                'icon'   => 'tachometer-alt',
                'route'  => route('admin.dashboard'),
                'active' => $this->getActiveClass('admin.dashboard'),
            ],

            ...

        ];

        View::share('navItems', $sideNavItems);
    }

    /**
     * @param $routeName
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function getActiveClass($routeName)
    {
        return (Route::current()->getName() == $routeName) ? 'active' : NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay solved it. Wrapped with a condition by checking the current route.

```
protected function getActiveClass($routeName)
{
    if (Route::is($routeName)) {
        return (Route::current()->getName() == $routeName) ? 'active' : NULL;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
if ($request->route()->named($routeName)) {
     return 'active';
}

return NULL;
```

[Laravel Inspecting The Current Route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to get the current route name

```
@if (request()->route())
@if (in_array(request()->route()->getName(), @$settings->getArray()))

@endif
@endif
```

By checking on top `request()->route()` we can avoid `null` error. and `request()->route()->getName()` will give the route name.